Is there a way to use a Javascript function from a js file via your custom snippet on load?
What am I trying to do?

There is an e-commerce site that obfuscates/hides the buyer information (on seller side of the platform) until you click on the switch to toggle a SWITCH-ON state.
I am trying to create a chrome extension that automatically SWITCH-ON the switch and displays user information on page load (among other things)

What have I found?

The switch is not a normal switch, but a bootstrap version made with Next.js
I copied the HTML element during the SWITCH-OFF state as well as the SWITCH-ON state, and noticed a few attributes changing.

What did I assume?

Changing attribute from the SWITCH-OFF state to the SWITCH-ON state would display hidden information.
HINT: It did not. There is an in-built js file containing a function that does this. I found this while debugging with a breakpoint.

What have I done so far?

I made a snippet to target the button and change it's state
It does change and displays a changed state, but the information is still hidden. When I manually toggle the SWITCH-ON(looking) button, it does not change state, and then actually works to display information. Thereby, working as intended.


This is what it looks like:

There is a DIV role=”switch” based switch toggle like the following in the code

When manually toggled, the details are revealed (I want this part to happen automatically on page load)

Attributes were modified to be made identical to the SWITCH-ON state, but the details were not revealed.



Show me the code?

HTML for the SWITCH-OFF state

<!-- OFF SWITCH LOOKS LIKE THIS -->
<div class="next-box custom-switch-selector" style="flex-flow: column; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; display: flex;">
    <div role="switch" tabindex="0" data-spm="d_buyer_sensitive_switch" data-more="209304361529099_true"
        class="next-switch next-switch-off next-switch-small aplus-auto-exp" aria-checked="false"
        data-aplus-ae="x38_42bab7ea"
        data-spm-anchor-id="Seller_NP.18660942.d_buyer_shipping_address.d_buyer_sensitive_switch.4a904edfouBzrd"
        data-aplus-clk="x38_47ece9ab">
        <div class="next-switch-btn"></div>
        <div class="next-switch-children"
            data-spm-anchor-id="Seller_NP.18660942.d_buyer_sensitive_switch.i0.4a904edfouBzrd"></div>
    </div>
</div>


HTML for the SWITCH-ON state

<!-- ON SWITCH LOOKS LIKE THIS -->
<div class="next-box custom-switch-selector" style="flex-flow: column; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; display: flex;">
    <div role="switch" tabindex="0" data-spm="d_buyer_sensitive_switch" data-more="209304361529099_false"
        class="next-switch next-switch-on next-switch-small aplus-auto-exp" aria-checked="true"
        data-aplus-ae="x38_42bab7ea"
        data-spm-anchor-id="Seller_NP.18660942.d_buyer_shipping_address.d_buyer_sensitive_switch.4a904edfouBzrd"
        data-aplus-clk="x38_47ece9ab">
        <div class="next-switch-btn" data-spm-anchor-id="Seller_NP.18660942.d_buyer_sensitive_switch.i1.4a904edfouBzrd">
        </div>
        <div class="next-switch-children"
            data-spm-anchor-id="Seller_NP.18660942.d_buyer_sensitive_switch.i0.4a904edfouBzrd"></div>
    </div>
</div>


When I add an attribute-change breakpoint in Inspect Element, it breaks at this function

var n = function(t, e, n) {
if (t && t.setAttribute)
try {
t.setAttribute(e, n)
} catch (t) {}
};


Chrome shows the following context for the variables t, e, n
t = div.next-switch.next-switch-on.next-switch-small.aplus-auto-exp {__reactInternalInstance$h4n036gxgak: bi, __reactEventHandlers$h4n036gxgak: {…}, checked: true, align: '', title: '', …}, e = "data-spm-anchor-id", n = "Seller_NP.18660942.d_buyer_shipping_address.d_buyer_sensitive_switch.4a904edfouBzrd"

The whole js file for the above part of code is given as a fiddle here



FINALLY, here is a fiddle you can try.

I could not make the switch work at all



const orderno = 209386708264213;
const custSwitchselector = document.getElementsByClassName("next-box custom-switch-selector")[0];
const custSwitch = custSwitchselector.getElementsByClassName("next-switch")[0];

// Modify Attributes of Div from OFF to ON state
custSwitch.setAttribute("aria-checked", true);
custSwitch.setAttribute("data-more", orderno + '_false');
custSwitch.setAttribute("class", 'next-switch next-switch-on next-switch-small aplus-auto-exp');

//Store Anchor value
const anchor = custSwitch.getAttribute("data-spm-anchor-id");
const frontanchor = 'Seller_NP.18660942.d_buyer_shipping_address.d_buyer_sensitive_switch.'
var endanchor = anchor.replace(frontanchor, "").trim();

//Create Anchors for Button and Child
nextSwitchbutton = custSwitch.getElementsByClassName("next-switch-btn")[0];
nextSwitchchild = custSwitch.getElementsByClassName("next-switch-children")[0];
switchbuttonAnchor = frontanchor
switchbuttonAnchor += "i1."
switchbuttonAnchor += endanchor
switchchildAnchor = frontanchor
switchchildAnchor += "i0."
switchchildAnchor += endanchor

// Modify Attributes of Button and Children
nextSwitchbutton.setAttribute("data-spm-anchor-id", switchbuttonAnchor)
nextSwitchchild.setAttribute("data-spm-anchor-id", switchchildAnchor)

//At this point SWITCHED-OFF switch is IDENTICAL to SWITCHED-ON switch
// But the Details are not revealed
//
// Is there a way to simulate the toggle of the switch on page open?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- The Bootstrap used for the styling is Next js and Next css based -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://g.alicdn.com/code/npm/@alife/aidc-fusion-theme/3.26.11/DARAZ/next.min.css" />
  <script src="https://g.alicdn.com/code/npm/@alife/aidc-fusion-theme/3.26.11/DARAZ/next.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Example of Switched OFF Switch -->
  <div class="next-box custom-switch-selector" style="flex-flow: column; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; display: flex;">
    <div role="switch" tabindex="0" data-spm="d_buyer_sensitive_switch" data-more="209304361529099_true" class="next-switch next-switch-off next-switch-small aplus-auto-exp" aria-checked="false" data-aplus-ae="x38_42bab7ea" data-spm-anchor-id="Seller_NP.18660942.d_buyer_shipping_address.d_buyer_sensitive_switch.4a904edfh1RhSk"
      data-aplus-clk="x38_47ece9ab">
      <div class="next-switch-btn" data-spm-anchor-id="Seller_NP.18660942.d_buyer_sensitive_switch.i0.4a904edfh1RhSk">
      </div>
      <div class="next-switch-children"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




Did you try simulating a click on the switch?  Modifying the switch’s appearance is unlikely to trigger code that hides or shows the address.

@james Wow, that was so obvious and staring at my face. I just did not know it was possible and had the search terms to look it up. Thank you!

Haha, figuring out the right thing to google is 90% of the battle.  Happy to help.

This is so stupid, but the answer is
document.getElementsByClassName("next-switch-children")[0].click()

It never occurred to me that a click could simply be simulated. Writing this answer despite the easy fix to save someone else from this quagmire.
Thankyou, James
